# loop through rows of one csv file to find corresponding data in another

Tags: python, csv

I got an interesting problem:

file1.csv has a few hundred rows like:

```
Code,DTime
1,2010-12-26 17:01
2,2010-12-26 17:07
2,2010-12-26 17:15
```

file2.csv has about 11 million rows like:

```
id,D,Sym,DateTime,Bid,Ask
1375022797,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:00:15,1.311400,1.311700
1375022965,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:00:56,1.311200,1.311500
1375022984,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:00:56,1.311300,1.311600
1375023013,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:01:01,1.311200,1.311500
1375023039,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:01:02,1.311100,1.311400
1375023055,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:01:03,1.311200,1.311500
1375023063,D,USD,2010-12-26 17:01:03,1.311300,1.311600
```

What i'm trying to do is to write a script that takes each DTime value in file1.csv and finds the first instance of a partial match in the DateTime column of file2.csv, and outputs DateTime, Bid, Ask for that row. The partial match is on the first 16 characters.

Both files are sorted from oldest to newest, so if "2010-12-26 17:01" from file1.csv matched 4 entries in file2.csv, I only need to extract the first one: "2010-12-26 17:01:01"

Not sure how to proceed..  I tried a dictionary but the order of values is important so i'm not sure if that would work. Maybe bring file1's DTime column into a list and for each entry in that list search DateTime in file2?

Thanks guys

Comment: The problem is less interesting if you throw it into a database and do a join ;)

Comment: I tried a database approach in access and mysql, but ran into issues trying to left join the two tables. The only sql query that ran fast was SELECT TOP 1 DateTime, Bid, Ask FROM tblTicks WHERE (DateTime) LIKE '2010-12-26 17:01*'; and when I tried to do any iterations with the first table, it freezes.. though python would handle it a bit better..

Comment: Doing a string search with a wildcard is definitely going to be slow. Id suggest the database approach for when you have the time and resources to migrate properly. Consider these kinds of slow queries when selecting your indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have duplicate `DTime` values, this should work:

```
import csv

file1reader = csv.reader(open("file1.csv"), delimiter=",")
file2reader = csv.reader(open("file2.csv"), delimiter=",")

header1 = file1reader.next() #header
header2 = file2reader.next() #header

for Code, DTime in file1reader:
    for id_, D, Sym, DateTime, Bid, Ask in file2reader:
        if DateTime.startswith(DTime): # found it
            print DateTime, Bid, Ask   # output data
            break                      # break and continue where we left next time
```

**Edit**

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

file1reader = csv.reader(open("file1.csv"), delimiter=",")
file2reader = csv.reader(open("file2.csv"), delimiter=",")

header1 = file1reader.next() #header
header2 = file2reader.next() #header

for Code, DTime in file1reader:
    DTime = datetime.strptime(DTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    for id_, D, Sym, DateTime, Bid, Ask in file2reader:
        DateTime = datetime.strptime(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if DateTime>=DTime: # found it
            print DateTime, Bid, Ask   # output data
            break                      # break and continue where we left next time
```

Comment: This almost worked! It actually found an issue with my data in file2. When looking for "2010-01-06 20:00" it didn't find it.. instead the the nearby values in file2 were "2010-01-06 19:59:20" and "2010-01-06 20:01:14" - ideally i'll take whatever is next in the sequence, the 20:01:14. Would the 'datetime' class be necessary here?

Comment: can you verify if `if DateTime.startswith(DTime):` just needs to be changed to `if DateTime >= DTime:`  this seems to actually do it.

Comment: tried both: >= and datetime worked perfectly! thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user1249464: ah, right. `>=` without `datetime` would also work since your date formats are sortable.

Comment: I think i'm going to do more work on the resulting data. Should i load it into a dictionary using id_ as the key? I guess i just need to replace the print line right?

Comment: @user1249464: Yes, changing the print line would do. Store them however you want to access them later.

Comment: Hi i have a follow up question if you can take a look please: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577997/search-through-csv-from-specific-row-down)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you only need to do this once, you should really use a database. Add a column to table2 that contains DATETIME without the seconds, so that you can join on exact matches, not with LIKE.

It WILL be fast, and even faster if you index those columns. And if you can store file1.csv in the database too, you don't need iterations: You can get the entire set of results in a single select query. This is the kind of stuff SQL is made for.

PS. If you decide to pursue this approach, you can ask for help with the query.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dictionary from file2, where the key is the prefix of the time you want, and the value is either first row, or all the rows matching this prefix.
then it's simply a matter of doing something like:

```
entries = file2Dict.get(file1Entry)
if entries:
   print  "First entry is %s" entries[0]
```