# Search through csv from specific row down

Tags: python, csv

This is a follow up to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564322/loop-through-rows-of-one-csv-file-to-find-corresponding-data-in-another)

The code I'm using is:

```
import csv

file1reader = csv.reader(open("file1.csv"), delimiter=",")
file2reader = csv.reader(open("file2.csv"), delimiter=",")

header1 = file1reader.next() #header
header2 = file2reader.next() #header

for Code, DTime in file1reader:
    for id_, D, Sym, DateTime, Bid, Ask in file2reader:
        if DateTime.startswith(DTime):            # found it
            print id_, Code, DateTime, Bid, Ask   # output data
            break                                 # break and continue where we left next time
```

Sample result:

```
1375023013 1 2010-12-26 17:01:01 1.311200 1.311500
1375023592 2 2010-12-26 17:07:16 1.311700 1.312000
1375024176 2 2010-12-26 17:15:04 1.311300 1.311600
```

With each row of these results, I want to search for the id_ value back in file2.csv, and from that row down, search column Bid for the value that is >= Bid+0.0010 OR <= Bid-0.0015. Basically, from that entry onwards, what price comes first? Bid+0.0010 or Bid-0.0015? I need to use >= & <= since the prices are not continuous. Once that entry is found, I want to append the original result by adding a column for the found DateTime and Bid.

Expected result:

```
id_      Code     DateTime       Bid      Ask      NextDateTime        NextBid      
1375023013 1 2010-12-26 17:01:01 1.311200 1.311500 2010-12-26 17:03:02 1.312200
1375023592 2 2010-12-26 17:07:16 1.311700 1.312000 2010-12-26 17:09:03 1.311100
1375024176 2 2010-12-26 17:15:04 1.311300 1.311600 2010-12-26 17:20:02 1.312400
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

To "search through csv from specific row down", try using [*itertools.dropwhile*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile).

To "append the original result by adding a column", you will need to rewrite the file with the new data.  The [*fileinput module*](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) makes that easy to do when *inplace* is set to true).

Comment: would it be better if i used a dictionary to store the first set of results like `d[id_] = Code, DateTime, Bid, Ask` and do something like `for k in sorted(d.keys()): re.search(k, file2reader)`?

Comment: @user1249464 There are many ways to do this.  A dictionary isn't indicated because it is unordered and because you aren't doing *id* based lookups.  Scanning a list would work equally well.  The *fileinput* approach may be simplest of all because you read and test and write all in one pass through the data.

Comment: +1 for use of `itertools` instead of some kind of kludgy loop. Is there anything `itertools` can't do?

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to python- can you walk me through how you would do it? thanks