# Writing a value in a csv column based on another value in another csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am trying to search all the rows in a specific column in a csv file to see if they contain a string in another csv file. If they contain that string I want to write the corresponding value to another specific column.

For example file1:

```
Search Value,Location
UK,United Kingdom
United Kingdom,United Kingdom
United States,United States
Hong Kong,Hong Kong
Florida,"Florida, United States"
```

and file2:

```
Name,Default,Geo Location
DRE UK,,
Production United States,,
Development Hong Kong,,
United Kingdom Sales,,
Florida Marketing,,
```

I want to find rows in which the Name from file2 contains the string from Search Value in file1 then write the corresponding value from Location in file1 to Geo Location in file2. So the outcome is like this:

```
Name,Default,Geo Location
DRE UK,,United Kingdom
Production United States,,United States
Development Hong Kong,,Hong Kong
United Kingdom Sales,,United Kingdom
Florida Marketing,,"Florida, United States"
```

I was looking for an answer and I came across [loop through rows of one csv file to find corresponding data in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564322/loop-through-rows-of-one-csv-file-to-find-corresponding-data-in-another). I started code based on that, but I don't know if it's the right thing and I am stuck.

```
import csv

file1reader = csv.reader(open('file1.csv','rb'))
file2reader = csv.reader(open('file2.csv','rb'))
writer=csv.writer(open('file3.csv','wb'))

header1 = file1reader.next() #header
header2 = file2reader.next() #header


for Search Value, Location in file1reader:
    for Name, Default, Geo Location in file2reader:
        if Search Value in Name: # found it
```

The data provided is an example of what I want to do. The actual files are going to be quite big, so keep that in mind.

Any help is appreciated.

*EDIT*

If I wanted to include the original lines from file2.csv in the final output (file3.csv) that didn't match the condition as well, how would I do that?

Example if file2 was like this instead and I wanted the non matching lines included too:

```
Name,Default,Geo Location
DRE UK,,
Production United States,,
Development Hong Kong,,
United Kingdom Sales,,
Florida Marketing,,
Stuff,,Somewhere
More Stuff,,
```

Comment: Are your files sorted? The answer you're basing your code on assumes that both files are sorted by the same key. This is necessary for the approach used to be effective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example using the [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) classes:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

with open('file1.csv') as fin1,\
     open('file2.csv') as fin2,\
     open('file3.csv', 'wb') as fout:

    reader1 = DictReader(fin1)
    reader2 = DictReader(fin2)

    writer = DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=reader2.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for line2 in reader2:
        outline = dict(line2)
        fin1.seek(0) # resets the reader1 iterator
        for line1 in reader1:
            if line1['Search Value'] in line2['Name']:
                outline['Geo Location'] = line1['Location']
        writer.writerow(outline)
```

The complexity of this algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>), so, like [@maged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557132/63011) is pointing out, it's not very efficient.

Comment: How would I include lines from file2.csv that do not have a string from Name in Search Value as well? Like if there was other lines that didn't match the search and I want them included how they are in file3.csv as well? I tried to modify this to do that, and it didn't go so well.

Comment: @CircuitB0T You can invert the `for` loops and always write the `file2.csv` lines even if they don't match the search. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Your second solution worked very well for the nonmatching rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct.

Another solution though would be to load the file in memory, in a hash-table/dictionary structure to improve performance (avoid O(n^2)). But since you're working with large files, and you're not doing an exact match, it'll make this solution less than ideal.

You can also try to load the files to a hash-table struct, and have that written to file, to avoid memory errors (similar to a search indexer). This seems like overkill for what you want to do though.

Comment: But, how do I finish the code and write Location to Geo Location for matching lines?

Comment: Assuming you're writing it in file3: 
writer.writerow[name,'',Search_Value]

Comment: Have that in every loop, with values in case Search_Value isn't found. Also write a header to writer at the beginning