# Using pytube library to download youtube links from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, video, pytube

I'm trying to use the [pytube library](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) to download a bunch of links I have on a .csv file.

**EDIT:**

**WORKING CODE**:

```
   import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')

import os.path

from pytube import YouTube
from pprint import pprint

import csv
with open('onedialectic.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                yt = YouTube(row[1])
                path = os.path.join('/videos/',row[0])
                path2 = os.path.join(path + '.mp4')
                print(path2)
                if not os.path.exists(path2) :
                                print(row[0] + '\n')
                                pprint(yt.get_videos())
                                yt.set_filename(row[0])
                                video = yt.get('mp4', '360p')
                                video.download('/videos')
            except Exception as e:
                print("Passing on exception %s", e)
                continue
```

Comment: Why not use the python library instead of the command line tool?

Comment: Should I be importing the python library ? I don't know, I'm still a beginner on python and felt like using the command line tool would be easier.

Comment: Yes you should `import` it. See the **Library usage** section of the web page linked to in your question.

Comment: Thank you martineau. I did try before doing 'from pytube import YouTube' but I'm getting the error 'ImportError: No module named pytube'. I have it installed though.

Comment: missing the 'from' before pytube

Comment: Indeed! Changed it but new error comes up!

Comment: you haven't got it installed properly then

Comment: When I use it on the command line it works properly though!

Comment: Thank you! I did not have pyapi, I've just installed it!

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'm new around here so this was my first post! :)

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard ah its ok, you can always vote up in the future ;)

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install it you need to use

```
pip install pytube
```

and then in your code run

```
from pytube import YouTube
```

I haven't seen  any code examples of using this with csv though, are you sure it's supported?

You can download via command line directly using e.g.

```
$ pytube -e mp4 -r 720p -f Dancing Scene from Pulp Fiction http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y
```

`-e`,  `-f` and `-r` are optional, (extension, filename and resolution)

However for you I would suggest maybe the best thing is to put them all in a playlist and then use Jordan Mear's excellent [Python Youtube Playlist Downloader](https://github.com/jordoncm/youtube-dl-playlist)

On a footnote, usually all [external] libraries need to be imported. You can read more about importing here, [in the python online tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

You could maybe do something like this:

```
import csv
from pytube import YouTube

vidcsvreader = csv.reader(open("videos.csv"), delimiter=",")

header1 = vidcsvreader.next() #header


for id, url in vidcsvreader:
    yt = url  #assign url to var

    #set resolution and filetype
    video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')

    # set a destination directory for download
    video.download('/tmp/')

    break
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I do have it installed but still when I try running it as you've mentioned directly via command line I get this error  'usage: pytube [-h] [--extension EXT] [--resolution RES] [--path PATH]
              [--filename FILENAME]
              url
pytube: error: unrecognized arguments: from Pulp Fiction http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y'

Comment: Yeah, got it working now. Had to add the ' and ' between Dancing Scene from Pulp Fiction. Maybe this is what I'm missing adding on my code, I'll try it out.

Comment: I'll do that but it's not working yet! How can I show you how my code looks right now ? I'm pretty sure it's just a small thing missing now! :/

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard put it the 'from pytube import YouTube' at the top of your code

Comment: I would like to take this to chat but I can't because I'm on 6 rep. :/ Oh well, I've edited my code on my main page. Thing is I don't need to use pytube import YouTube because I'm using the command line and calling it using subprocess and call.

Comment: I've added it but I'm getting this error now ' File "running.py", line 1
    pytube import YouTube
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: 1,365 videos to be exact!

Comment: after proper installation you should do a for loop to loop through the csv and forget about the subprocess thing .. an example of looping through a csv is outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564322/loop-through-rows-of-one-csv-file-to-find-corresponding-data-in-another  Also here http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Comment: Thank you! I'll be doing the same in a bit.

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard how are you getting on? any progress?

Comment: yes! I've already figured it out and got it all working! I'll edit my code in a sec :) Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard no probs always happy to help :)