# CSV columns loop into variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, csv

Trying to do something something similar to this Powershell script in Python 3.6:

```bsh
$apiKey = "key-example" 
$HostPA = "https://ip-address" 
$file = "addressObjects.csv" 
$addressObject = Import-Csv $file

foreach($line in $addressObject) 
{ 
    $name = $line.name 
    $ip = $line.ip_netmask

    Invoke-WebRequest "$HostPA/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='$name']&element=$ip&key=$apikey"
}
```

This would take a column (Excel style) CSV file and pass each line to an API request.

I've got the API request part down (the piece that won't work in PowerShell), but not the foreach statement. I tried a few things, but got nowhere.

This is what works so far:

```python
apiKey = 'key-example'
HostPA = 'ip-address'

import csv 
File = open('addressObjects.csv') 
File_Reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',')

import requests
r = requests.get(HostPA + "/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='" + name + "']&element=" + ip + "&key=" + apiKey, verify=False)

with open("results.xml", "wb") as f: f.write(r.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

For example, if I had a CSV file like this:

```
name, ip
test, 8.8.8.8
test2, 8.8.4.4
```

I would want to take each row and assign it to a variable that would go to the corresponding place in the "requests.get" URL

the first row would translate"

```
HostPA + "/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='" + name + "']&element=" + ip + "&key=" + apiKey
```

into this:

```
https://HostIP/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='test']&element=8.8.8.8&key=Somekey
```

and then loop through the other rows

My questions is different from The proposed duplicate:  [loop through rows of one csv file to find corresponding data in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564322/loop-through-rows-of-one-csv-file-to-find-corresponding-data-in-another)

This question asked to match data between two CSV files. The CSV format is the same as mine. 
My question asks to take columned CSV data and loop through each row, creating a variable from each, so I can push it into separate API calls.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**EDIT :**
Here's My Solution:

```
apiKey = 'MyKey'
HostPA = 'https://IP'

import requests
import csv 
filereader = csv.reader(open('C:/addressObjects.csv'), delimiter=',') #import csv
header = filereader.__next__()

#Header names       
for name, ip in filereader: 
     (print(name, ip))

     r = requests.get(HostPA + "/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='" + name + "']&element=<ip-netmask>" + ip + "</ip-netmask>&key=" + apiKey, verify=False) #API call
     print(r.text) #Check API results
```

Comment: For each line in the csv file you want to make a request and deposit the results as a line in an xml file? You're going to include code that specified values for name, ip apiKey, etc in your Python code?

Comment: name, ip
test, 8.8.8.8
test2, 8.8.4.4

for this CSV example I would want to take each row and assign it to a variable that would go to the corresponding place in the "requests.get" URL

Comment: name, ip
test, 8.8.8.8
test2, 8.8.4.4

for this I want to take each row and assign it to a variable that would go to the corresponding place in the "requests.get" URL

the first row would translate
HostPA + "/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='" + name + "']&element=" + ip + "&key=" + apiKey

into:
https://HostIPHostPA/api/?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/vsys/entry[@name='vsys1']/address/entry[@name='test']&element=8.8.8.8&key=Somekey

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers: This is not a duplicate. Pls see edit.

Comment: Assuming you have variables name, ip and apiKey in the same (ie, local) scope you can format them in a string most simply using:

"http://www.myhost.ca/%(name)s/%(ip)s/somethin%(apiKey)s"%locals()

Comment: @BillBell This question is about iterating over a CSV and using values from the CSV fields. That is exactly what is answered in the duplicate question. If you disagree: feel free to vote to reopen. However, please refrain from editing your opinion into the question.

Comment: That's the advice I had from the SO help file. I still disagree with you. The other question is entirely about Python.

Comment: @Ansgar-wiechars: I meant to say the other question involves no language translation. Please reconsider.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers edited for clarification.

Comment: *"My question asks to take columned CSV data and loop through each row, creating a variable from each"* What do you think the accepted answer to the other question is doing?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it looks like it's searching for corresponding data between two different CSV's and printing the matching data.

Comment: It's using two loops for two CSV files. Other than that it does exactly what you say you want. If you're looking for someone to spoon-feed you a translation of your PowerShell code you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Please take a look at the accepted answer to the other question. Again. Does it read the entire row into a single variable? If not, why are you? Why do you append the values to arrays and try to do a single API call with all values *after* the loop instead of doing one call per CSV row *inside* the loop? As for `print`: put parentheses around the argument list (`print('a', 'b', 'c')`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you, that let me to a resolution.